# memcached test not behaving as expected

Tags: java, spring, junit, memcached, spymemcached

I'm implementing https://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/ and when I run below code I receive this output :

```
Adding to cache
Adding to cache
```

Code which tests memcached :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory;
import com.google.code.ssm.api.ParameterValueKeyProvider;
import com.google.code.ssm.api.ReadThroughSingleCache;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:memcached-context.xml" })
public class MemcachedTest {

    @Test
    public void testMemcached() {
        Assert.assertTrue(getComplexObjectFromDB("test").size() == 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(getComplexObjectFromDB("test").size() == 1);
    }

    private List<String> getSA(){

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Adding to cache");
        l.add("test");

        return l;
    }

    @ReadThroughSingleCache(namespace = "CplxObj", expiration = 3600)
    public List<String> getComplexObjectFromDB(@ParameterValueKeyProvider String id) {

        return getSA();
    }

    @Autowired
    private CacheFactory defaultMemcachedClient;

}
```

memcached-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

<import resource="simplesm-context.xml" />
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean name="defaultMemcachedClient" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
          <property name="cacheClientFactory">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
          </property>
          <property name="addressProvider">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
                     <property name="address" value="xx.xx.xx.xx:11211" />
                </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="configuration">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
                      <property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
                </bean>
          </property>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

I expect to just receive output "Adding to cache" once as once the cache is added to the List should be returned and the List should not be re-instantiated ? Is my implementation correct ?

Update :

based on @raznor suggestion here this seems to behave as expected :

memcached-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
   http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

<import resource="simplesm-context.xml" />
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean name="memcachedClient" class="com.memcached.MemcachedClient">
     </bean>

    <bean name="defaultMemcachedClient" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
          <property name="cacheClientFactory">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
          </property>
          <property name="addressProvider">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
                     <property name="address" value="1.1.1.1:11211" />
                </bean>
          </property>
          <property name="configuration">
                <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
                      <property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
                </bean>
          </property>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

MemcachedTest.java :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory;
import com.google.code.ssm.api.ParameterValueKeyProvider;
import com.google.code.ssm.api.ReadThroughSingleCache;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:memcached-context.xml" })
public class MemcachedTest {

    @Test
    public void testMemcached() {

        Assert.assertTrue(mClient.getComplexObjectFromDB("test1").size() == 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(mClient.getComplexObjectFromDB("test1").size() == 1);
    }

    @Autowired
    private MemcachedClient mClient;

}
```

MemcachedClient.java :

```
package com.memcached;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.code.ssm.api.ParameterValueKeyProvider;
import com.google.code.ssm.api.ReadThroughSingleCache;

public class MemcachedClient {

    @ReadThroughSingleCache(namespace = "CplxObj", expiration = 3600)
    public List<String> getComplexObjectFromDB(
            @ParameterValueKeyProvider String id) {

        return getSA();
    }

    private List<String> getSA() {

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Adding to cache");
        l.add("test");

        return l;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because self invocations are not intercepted. To make it work extract getComplexObjectFromDB method to separated Spring bean and call it in your test using this bean: myBean.getComplexObjectFromDB.

Comment: thanks, this seems to be working for me now, I have updated question. Can you verify my implmentation is correct ? The spring bean defaultMemcachedClient is required to configure the "Simple Spring Memcached" itself but should not be referenced directly within custom client code ?

Comment: Yes, bean like defaultMemcachedClient is required to provide physical connection and settings to memcached instance (using some of available providers). You don't have to reference it in your code but you can if you want to get direct access to memcached commands: get, set, add, ....

Comment: Your implementation is correct. You may also integrate SSM with Spring Cache and use @Cacheable annotation.